# jQuery mouseover fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been learning how to do a Jquery mouse over effect from 
http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/

How do I have three separate buttons with this effect? I keep having a problem of the Divs overlapping when i duplicate them and I can't move them away from each other. Sorry if my initial question was confusing! 
Here is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/japaneselanguagefriend/EgDqy/

```
<div class="fadehover"><img src="button 1" alt="" class="a" /><img src="button 1 roll" alt="" class="b" /></div>

<div class="fadehover"><img src="button 2" alt="" class="c" /><img src="button 2 roll" alt="" class="d" /></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I am also confused. What do you mean by "move them apart".. isn't this a fade-in/out problem? What movement?

Comment: Basically, how do I have three separate buttons? I keep having a problem of the Divs overlapping when i duplicate them and I can't move them away from each other.  Sorry if my initial question was confusing!

Comment: @PaperThick I think the fiddle shows the "normal" case where fade in/out replaces one image by another. So the overlapping in that case is normal in my opinion. I think the OP wants to have several of those one one page. Is this correct?

Comment: @Chris Yes that is correct, thank you for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that should start you on the right path:

http://jsfiddle.net/EgDqy/12/

```
<div class="cell">

<img src="http://www.charlesayoub.com/news/public/uploads/images/895377521.jpeg" alt="" display /> 

<img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/smart-car-1.jpg" class="fader" alt="" />

</div>


<div class="cell"> 

<img src="http://www.charlesayoub.com/news/public/uploads/images/895377521.jpeg" alt="" /> 

<img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/smart-car-1.jpg" class="fader" alt="" />

</div>

<div class="cell"> 

<img src="http://www.charlesayoub.com/news/public/uploads/images/895377521.jpeg" alt="" /> 

<img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/smart-car-1.jpg" class="fader" alt="" />

</div>​


$(".cell").hover(
   function() {
      $(this).find('.fader').fadeOut("slow");
   },
   function() {
      $(this).find('.fader').fadeIn("slow");
   }
);


.cell{ width:100px; display:inline-block; position:relative; }
.cell img { width:100px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

Comment: Perfect! This got me started on exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Basically because the inner elements of the div's are absolute positioned, the div's do not have any measurements (there is a technical word for this but is escapes me). You basically need to explicitly set the width and height of the div's. You can do this in CSS or dynamically generate the css in javascript/jquery. Here is an example using jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/EgDqy/13/

Example paints a thousands words, this may help others understand the problem if they see this question. Click the button on the right

http://jsfiddle.net/EgDqy/16/